# How to stop IE for scrolling *hidden* overflowed content

Tags: html, css

I have some content that overflows as part of a larger layout, which is generally wider than the page. The overflowing content is clipped by one of its containers, which is fine, except that in IE9 clicking the clipping container and using a mouse based horizontal scroll (think touchpad, ultranav, mighty mouse) causes all the content in the container to scroll until the edge of the clipped content is visible. I need to prevent this behavior while still allowing those mouse to scroll the outer container. It seems to me like capturing scroll events on that element and causing them to instead be passed to its parent would be fine, but I've not yet figured out how to get jQuery to do that. If anyone can think of a non-JS solution, that'd be cool too.

UPDATE:
Some probing reveals the following: since different HID's send scrolling events differently (I'm looking at you synaptic), the only event that will always be fired is the scroll event. The scroll event has no bubbling phase and cannot be cancelled. Furthermore the results of simply setting scroll to 0 as part of the scroll handler are poor. This effectively rules out all javascript solutions that work for the majority of devices that are capable of generating input to scroll sideways. My next course of attack is through click events. Clicks do bubble, and for the undesired behavior to occur one must first click on the offending overflow:hidden div. If I can prevent focus then it will never become the target of scroll events. The real trick will be making links continue to work.

A fiddle demonstrating the issue is
http://jsfiddle.net/conartist6/tnmT3/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer"><div class="ctnr"><div>Click in here and scroll r/l with wheel or midclick+drag. IE9 moves content, Chrome/FF do not.<div>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div></div></div>
    <div style="width: 700px;">This should still scroll normally blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah lajsof ijwjlk jdslf kjojfoj jjslfj sljfoi jdfoiaj ;lsajoi fejogro lfffos joidjgoe wqqqq</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer
{
    width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.ctnr{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: violet;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ctnr > div
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.ctnr>div>div
{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:400px;
    background-color: salmon;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I see a horizontal scroll bar in Chrome. Not understanding the question or problem.

Comment: Thats just there so anyone testing a solution can make sure it doesn't break something else. As mentioned you'll need IE9 and an input device that can scroll horizontally in order to follow the instructions properly and see the bug.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this should be the answer you're looking for:

*Use the id of the container that you don't want to be able to scroll.

```
//Firefox uses a different event that is **not cancelable** for mousewheel, of course there is a work around
//Since you only need IE though, here it is:
$('#divID').on('mousewheel', function(event) { //for all browsers except Firefox
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Note: I use a touch pad, so I cannot test this, but I'm pretty sure it will work, just make sure that you target only the div (use an id tag) that you want to prevent the default action to.

For future reference, a great website for looking up DOM elements, events, and other DOM architecture, as well as compatibility, is [the Dottoro Web Reference](http://help.dottoro.com/).

Just so you know, the scroll event is not cancelable, see [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php); however, the mousewheel event is... so [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmracjb.php)

Comment: This was my very first thought. I tested it and it did not work. You can see the fiddle with that solution at http://jsfiddle.net/conartist6/tnmT3/7/

Comment: Touchpads should work if you have edge or two finger scrolling enabled. I think you're onto something with the mousewheel event though. That is the only way that scroll would be generated on that element, so I'm almost certain that canceling it there would prevent the accidental scrolling. Then all I need to figure out is how to trigger that same event (complete with original event data) on the container's parent which should actually be scrolling.

Comment: No, don't use the scroll event, that is *not* cancelable. Use the mousewheel as I have defined it. I will change your jsFiddle, then please try it again.

Comment: I changed your jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/tnmT3/8/ Oh I see what you're saying. You want to disable scrolling on the inner div, but when the user uses the scroll on the inner div, the parent div which contains it is caused to scroll. Is that an accurate description?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm playing with mousewheel event and so far I haven't been able to capture one at all. I stuck an alert in the handler and it never fires even if I put in on the outer scrolling container which has absolutely nothing funky going on.

Comment: I wonder if its because of the version of IE you are using. I included a handler for both, `onmousewheel` and `mousewheel` Try here http://jsfiddle.net/tnmT3/21/ . It works for me with using `mousewheel` but that is for IE 9 and above. Please take a look at this page for reference about the event, it's an important skill to beable to read and understand the event information  http://help.dottoro.com/ljmracjb.php